# Make element of materialize modal window not scrollable

Tags: html, css, angular, materialize

I have code for materialize modal window

```
<div class="modal" materialize="modal" [materializeActions]="modal_questions">
<div class="modal-header">
  <i class="modal-action material-icons right" (click)="closeModal()">close</i>
</div>
<div class="modal-content">
  <h4 class="center">Title</h4>
  <!--some text-->
</div>
</div>
```

In css I have:

```
.modal-header {
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

But modal header is still scrollable, not fixed. How to fix header on the top of modal window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about IE, you can use `position:sticky;`. Here is the [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

```
.modal-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: white; //the color of your modal background
    height: 32px;
    padding: 4px; //Material guidelines suggests "Iconography in toolbars align to a 4dp/px square baseline grid."
}
```

[image]

Comment: great, it works. And do you know how to make some padding or something for modal-header to replace it under header even after scroll?

Comment: @DzouSi I edited my answer, this should fulfill your needs.